# Overwriting a CSS Class How to?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Soft.CSS file which has following class

```
.check_out {
width:58px;
background-image:url(/a/i/softadd/checkout.gif);}
```

What i want to do here is change this Class ( please note that i DO NOT have access to Soft.CSS as it is fed from some other server ) to

```
.check_out {
width:58px;
background-image:url(/myserver/checkout.gif);}
```

How do i do it ? using CSS ? Using Jquery ?

Comment: I think you can just add your code to your css file and make sure it's loaded after Soft.CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be enough if you make sure that your piece of css comes AFTER the `Soft.css` file. Most browsers only pick the last definition they find when they find double entries of the same identification.

Elsewise, you could parse the `Soft.css` file with PHP and do some regex on `background-image` and find the file name.

*UPDATE*
An alternative answer:

Have you thought of adding another class on every element that has the `check_out`-class? You could write your own css on some other class like `check_out_ow` and add it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // every element gets an extra class with custom information
    $('check_out').addClass('check_out_ow');
});
```

I'm not sure, but I **hope** that the information of two classes lies deeper than of one class. Your css could look like:

```
.check_out.check_out_ow {
width:58px;
background-image:url(/myserver/checkout.gif);}
```

Comment: It's not "most browsers" it's any conforming browser that processes the last definition. That is why these are "Cascading" stylesheets.

Comment: Yes that is what I remember, but I do remember that there were some old browsers that did it the other way around. But you are right, I can't come up with a good reference for that fact.

Comment: Thanks that helps i overwritten the CSS by adding a new CSS with my required class after Soft.css

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redefine exactly the rule itself, not the respective css properties, well, you do have such an opportunity in javascript (not jquery)

There is document.styleSheets collection we can access. Each item is CSSStyleSheet, which has cssRules collection. But Schroedingers Cat is right, there are rare occasions when we really need to access rules directly.

Check [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) classic reference if you want mess up with DOM CSS.

But in your case it will definitely be better, as already metioned, to add a separate stylesheet with redefined rules.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, you only need to add your rule, either in another CSS file or directly to the page in `<style>` tags, after you include Soft.css.

If the order in which your CSS files are attached is also out of your control you can use increased specificity to ensure that your rule is seen as more important:

```
div.check_out { /* assuming the element is a div */
width:58px;
background-image:url(/myserver/checkout.gif);}
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is to give your style a higher specificity, no matter it was loaded after `soft.CSS` **or even it was loaded before**,
all you have to do is to make your CSS selector for `.check_out` have a higher specificity, by just adding any parent class (or even ID will be better), so lets say you have a `<div id="wrapper">`, that wraps all elements, then you can override your style as:

```
#wrapper .check_out {
    width:58px;
    background-image:url(/myserver/checkout.gif);
}
```

also you can add this id to the body (for example) if you have access to that..

refer to the following [article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), to know more about specificity things

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('.check_out').css('background-image', '/myserver/checkout.gif');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/N9maB/)**

It will update all instances of `.check_out` in the output page. I assume this is exactly what you want. You don't want to edit the class in the stylesheet itself since you don't have access to it.

Answer (score -1):

A jquery approach would be to select on the class - $(".check_out") - and amend the css ( which I can't remember how to do ).

It does not change the class, but will change everything using the class. Of course, if you have to have the class changed because other elements are added using it, then this might not work.

It depends very much on your precise requirements and solution.

Comment: No need for a heavy handed JavaScript approach, CSS is designed to handle overriding in the cascade.

Comment: @shanethehat - a year ago there whose a cluster of issues you've just have to use css assignment from javascript. animation is a good example of such problem. and, once again, manipulating DOM CSSRules is much rare technique compare to setting style property.

Comment: Yes - but it depends hom much control you have over the page loading. This is an approach if you cannot use CSS overriding.

Comment: Fair enough for a last ditch solution, and for the record I wasn't your -1 :)